# How can I improve this on hold question to make it fit the requirements of this stack?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my The Workplace Stack Exchange post: [How to tell someone politely that they are barking up the wrong tree?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126974/how-to-tell-someone-politely-that-they-are-barking-up-the-wrong-tree)

The question is put on hold, how can I improve it?

Comment: Welcome to Workplace SE! Richard U's answer gives you some good tips for improving the question. The [ask] pages give some more general info but I don't think you'd go too far wrong with what Richard suggests.

Comment: FWIW, the post is now open again :)

Answer (score 8):

The best way would be to give a bit more detail, use more professional terminology, explain things a bit, and state your goal clearly.

You posted:

> R&D: MIS, something wrong, please rectify.
>
> MIS: HR, MIS need to XYZ, please advise.
>
> HR: Hi Finance, please advise so MIS can proceed to solve the issue.
>
> R&D: MIS, is this issue resolve?
>
> Everyone is in the email loop.
>
> It's pretty easy to tell it's pending for response from Finance, but R&D asking for response from MIS instead.
>
> How do MIS tell R&D politely that they are barking up the wrong tree?

You might want to do something like this.

### How do I point out, in a professional manner, that someone in an email chain has made a mistake?

then, go on like this.

R&D sent us an email, and included HR & finance.  HR responded and instructed finance to authorize payment so that we could proceed.

R&D followed up in the email chain asking if we had resolved the issue before Finance had even responded.

**How can I politely inform the person in R&D that we are still waiting for a response.**